# chrome extension - address bar focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to focus on the address bar using chrome extension API or some other JS? 
I want to focus the user once he's starting to type somewhere (same result as you open new tab in chrome and start typing in the search bar to search in google. It auto focus to the address bar).

Thanks!

Comment: The default new tab uses a private API exposed only for chrome's own code. There's no way for normal extensions to focus the address bar. Also, the focus jumping in the default new tab page is one of the worst UX examples I ever saw.

Comment: @wOxxOm - Thanks for the input. Bad UX example or not, it's what google is doing by default. Just out of curiosity - Why do you think it's bad?

Comment: Google is not absolved from making bad or even terrible UI decisions. A user already clicked the input and focused the attention there, but typing switches the focus to somewhere else, the bigger the display, the bigger the confusion and inconvenience.

Comment: I think @wOxxOm is right in context of the auto focusing in address bar. Although this is purely users choice whtat UI he likes and what he doesn't. Auto focusing doesn't make sense unless you have a explicit requirement for this.

Comment: Entering the debate, I don't think it is bad design from Google: When you open a new tab, you have an autofocus on the address bar, so the user doesn't have to click anywhere to enter his request, refocussing on the address bar is telling the user "it is happening here not in the lower input, you don't have to use this input the next time, just use the address bar and earn one click everytime from now on"; on the other hand, removing the input would be bad design because many people would be lost being used to the Google input that was there from day one when they weren't building browsers.